# Using if/else vs. switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm wondering if it would be better to use a `switch` statement in my specific case.

I'm writing an Alexa Custom Skill, and I need to "redirect" to the appropriate intent depending on the available information (aka slots). Below is what I have currently (using `if/else`):

```
if (_type === "IntentRequest") {

    this.handler.state = states.START;
    if (_slots.indexOf("address") != -1) {
        this.emitWithState("GoingToAddressIntent");
    } else if (_slots.indexOf("place") != -1) {
        this.emitWithState("GoingToPlaceIntent");
    } else if (_slots.indexOf("type") != -1) {
        this.emitWithState("GoingToTypeIntent");
    } else if (_slots.indexOf("purpose") != -1) {
        this.emitWithState("GoingToPurposeIntent");
    } else {
        this.emit("Unhandled");
    }

}
```

I expect `_slots` to be an array of any permutations of the four elements, `[ "address", "place", "type", "purpose" ]`. Therefore, it could be anything from `[ "address" ]` to `[ "place", "purpose" ]` to etc. etc., but *always in the same order* (e.g. `[ "purpose", "address" ]` would never happen).

The order of the comparisons matters because there is a "hierarchy" of information; so if the "address" slot is present, I have to `emit` the `"GoingToAddressIntent"` *regardless* of what other slots are available. Given this requirement, I thought using a `switch` statement maybe more straightforward and readable despite having to have a few extra lines of code to "convert" the array of strings to an array of booleans. It clearly lays out the hierarchy & make sure they are evaluated in order. I could do:

```
if (_type === "IntentRequest") {

    this.handler.state = states.START;
    slots = [ 
        _slots.indexOf("address") != -1,
        _slots.indexOf("place") != -1,
        _slots.indexOf("type") != -1,
        _slots.indexOf("purpose") != -1
    ]

    switch(slots.indexOf(true)) {
    case 0:
        this.emitWithState("GoingToAddressIntent");
        break;
    case 1:
        this.emitWithState("GoingToAddressIntent");
        break;
    case 2:
        this.emitWithState("GoingToTypeIntent");
        break;
    case 3:
        this.emitWithState("GoingToPurposeIntent");
        break;
    default:
        this.emit("Unhandled");
    }

}
```

... in which case I have an extra line to define the array of booleans, use `indexOf()` to get the index of the first occurrence of a `true` literal (because all 4 slots are always in the order of hierarchy), and run it through the switch statement. However I wanted ask experts on their ideas of what best programming practice is in this case and the reasoning behind it because I want this to become a long-term project that is maintainable, and also I believe I can learn something from their insights.

---

Please leave a comment if you think this should be migrated to another community on SE, but from my [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic) (although 3 years old) I believe this should be fine (I'm just not 100% confident on this).

Comment: Why does the second version use `.hasOwnProperty()` if `_slots` is an array? (Shouldn't the array of booleans be built using `.indexOf()!=-1` for each element?) In any case, I think the choice between the two versions is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @nnnnnn Does it make a difference? I thought `in`, `hasOwnProperty()`, and `indexOf() != -1` all essentially achieve the same thing (although `in` has its own caveats)

Comment: If they are always in priority order, then you don't need to check all elements of `_slots`.  You only need to check the first element and then behave accordingly.  If you do that then a switch would make sense.

Comment: If vs switch doesn't bother me nearly as much as the repetitive emitWithState lines

Comment: @OliviaRuth Ahahah, yeah but with Alexa SDK I don't have _that_ many options, the code tends to get rather repetitive... Although the answer about using a hash map looks interesting

Comment: No, your array doesn't have a property called `"address"`, it has an element with the *value* `"address"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh. Yeah you're right. Fixing that right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're always in the order of precedence in `_slots`, maybe you could make a hash map to the state you're going to emit...

```
const map = {
  address: "GoingToAddressIntent",
  place: "GoingToPlaceIntent",
  type: "GoingToTypeIntent",
  purpose: "GoingToPurposeIntent"
};

const state = map[_slots[0]];
if (state) {
  this.emitWithState(state);
} else {
  this.emit("Unhandled");
}
```

Comment: An object literal creates a plain object (which is an **unordered** collection of name/value pairs), not a "hash map". If that's what you want, use a [real *Map*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-map-constructor). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with your example of the switch statement. People could understand what you're attempting to do, but it does seem pretty convoluted. I use switch statements pretty liberally, mostly in backend code, and I think it could work fine here. A group of if/else is fine too, since there's only 4 cases you need to work through. Lets roll with the switch statement since that's what you're asking about.

Based on your explanation, the order is always going to be the same, although the first value you get may be different. So the solution would be to simply grab the first value, and switch over that.

```
if (!!slots.length) {
  var keyword = slots[0];
  switch (keyword) {
    case 'address':
        this.emitWithState("GoingToAddressIntent");
        break;
    case 'place':
        this.emitWithState("GoingToPlaceIntent");
        break;
    case 'type':
        this.emitWithState("GoingToTypeIntent");
        break;
    case 'purpose':
        this.emitWithState("GoingToPurposeIntent");
        break;
    default:
        this.emit('Unhandled'); // I typically throw an exception here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In regards to the comment on `Unhandled`, that's essentially Alexa's version of throwing an exception (: